# Using a ViewModel to Expose a Nested Model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm looking for a little guidance with a WPF/MVVM app I'm putting together. Google has not helped me today.

So I've got an application with some models(domain objects) which have other models as properties. Right now, I just flatten out the nested object, and expose the properties in the containing object's ViewModel.

As my models get more complex, I'm struggling with how to possibly break down the ViewModels somewhat. I'm leading toward a "Composite View", where the "containing" object has its View & ViewModel, and the "nested" object has its own as well. This would also give me some reusable code, which would be a plus.

As a super simple example, let's say I have a Building, and each building has some properties and along with an Address like so:

```
public class Building
{
     public string Name { get; set;}
     public Address Address { get; set;}
}

public class Address
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
}
```

Then, I have a ViewModel for the building, and a ViewModel (exposed by BuildingViewModel) for the Address:

```
public class BuildingViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; } // from model
    public AddressViewModel Address { get; set; } // a wrapped instance of Address
    // INPC, etc... 
}

public class AddressViewModel
{
    public string Number { get; set; } // originally from Building 
    public string Street { get; set; }
    // INPC, etc...
}
```

Accordingly, and not shown, I have a BuildingView and a nested AddressView. I'm simply using ViewModel first with datatemplates.

Now, how do I keep the Address object synchronized? As soon as I separate these into two ViewModels, I get two instances of the Address object. In all the searching I've done, I've seen using messaging the object back and forth, and the "Observer" pattern has been mentioned.

Am I headed in the right direction, or am I missing something really simple? Any suggestions are appreciated.

FWIW, I've cobbled together my own framework, as I've been leery of the learning curve. Plus, its been fairly simple so far.

Answer (score 1):

I think your current direction is exposing too much information, and prevents the model(s) and viewmodel(s) from being loosely coupled.

I would have only one instance of a model that encapsulates all the data (buildings and addresses). Any viewmodel would get hold of this one instance through a static method.

Then i would expose query methods in the model that interrogated your db, for example returning a list of results you could then populate your views with.

Note that the list need not be a list of buildings or adddresses, each list item would containing whatever is most useful to your viewmodel e.g some fields from a builidng, and others from a nested address record.

By the way, Wpf has a great mechanism for directly linking viewmodel data with views, for example a query result with a listbox, without the viewmodel needing to know anything about the view.

Comment: So how would this work? I mean, the Address field comes along with the Building instance from my data context (SQL).

Answer (score 1):

you can store your address in your AddressViewModel by using an backend field of type address:

```
    public class AddressViewModel
    {
        private readonly Address _address;

        public AddressViewModel(Address address)
        {
            _address = address;
        }

        public string Number 
        { 
            get { return _address.Number; }
            set { _adress.Number = value; }
        }
        public string Street
        { 
            get { return _address.Street; }
            set { _adress.Street = value; }
        }
    }
```

I hope you can do something with my code :-)

**edit:**

Next try :)

I think the best way to solve your problem is to use some factory classes/methods where you get your models from. For example you have a AddessList class with a method GetAddressList(). That method returns a list of your Address model objects. After the first call you cache the returned objects in the AddressList class and for the next calls you return the cached list.

```
    public static class AddressList
    {
        private static List<Address> _backend;

        private static AddressList()
        {
            _backend = new List<Address>();
        }

        public static List<Address> GetAddressList()
        {
            if(_backend.Count == 0)
            {
                //Here you can load your models from your data source
            }
            else
            {
                return _backend;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, Andre, but I do have backing fields for the properties. I omitted them to reduce the amount of code...